# jQuery 'Scroll to top' button which follows mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent

I'm trying to make my scroll to top link follow users' mouse when it enters the fixed div on the left side. I've made a fiddle of a prototype of what I am trying to do, but my skill is too low to actually make it work. Please help.

```
  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(".side").mousemove(function(e){
   mouseY = e.pageY-19; 
});

var follower = $("#follower");
yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){

    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 6;
    follower.css({top:yp});

}, 10);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grammakov/tDGRc/1

Comment: You'll need to explain what about this demo is not what you desire.

Comment: Yep, it looks pretty good to me!

Comment: if i paste it in the real html document, the button goes completely crazy.. try it yourself!

Comment: I don't know what you want to use this for, but I think it will be really annoying for some/most users...

Comment: i want to use it for the scroll to top, and in my opinion its gonna be Awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this in my website:

```
$("body").on( "mousemove" , "a.refreply",  function(e){ relocatePopup(e); });
```

when the mouse is on top a certain link with class "refreply", it shows a div#popup and if the mouse moves, the popup follows the cursor. The part that shows the popup is not shown here, it basically ends with $('#popup').show();

the function relocatePopup is:

```
function relocatePopup ( e, useglobal ) {

if ( useglobal == true ) {
    var e = new Object;
    e.pageX = global_x;
    e.pageY = global_y;
}

var popup_height = parseInt( $("div#popup").css("height") ) ;
var bottom_popup = e.pageY + popup_height + 20;
var bottom_page = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
if ( bottom_popup > bottom_page ) {
    $('div#popup').css("top", bottom_page - popup_height - 5 ).css("left",e.pageX+20);
}else{
    $("div#popup").css("top",e.pageY+20).css("left",e.pageX+20);
}
}
```

Basically it gets the x,y of the mouse event, and the rest is calculating if the content of the popup would appear outside of the visible screen, recalculating the position to keep the popup inside the page, and then changing the "top" and "left" of the element, which has to be absolutely positioned.